# How much speed is required to achieve lift on something that weighs 1000lbs?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

I was wondering how much speed would be needed to get an object that weighs about 1000 pounds to generate enough lift to get off the ground and achieve flight?

Comment: None, you can achieve lift at zero speed.

Comment: @RonBeyer considering that the lift formula I know has the speed as a multiplicative term, I am curious how you would achieve that. could you please write an answer?

Comment: @Federico My guess: helicopter.  Technically they can have lift when they have zero speed.

Comment: @CortAmmon you too: write an answer not a comment.

Comment: @Jon, your question shows no sign of research and has the appearance of "Let me ask someone to write an answer to save me looking it up." You could improve the question considerably by explaining (in the question) what you understand and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Federico actually I'm thinking about lighter than air vehicles.

Comment: 88 miles per hour, if you've kept your flux capacitor in good repair.

Comment: Zero, if that 1000 lbs is a bag full of helium :-)  Or if it's a rocket engine and fuel tanks.  But if it's say a 1000 lb block of concrete... well, good luck with that :-)  (Downvoted for being "not even wrong".)

Comment: This is someone that is apparently new to aerodynamics. Instead of pounding them into the dirt, why not try to help them?

Answer (score 3):

**Lift Formula For Fixed Wing**

You need more information than just speed. The lift formula shows all the variables that must be known in order to calculate lift.

[image]

Most countries require pilots to know the *Lift Formula* by heart and is part of their written and oral test:

```
L = (lb) lift
CL = (dimensionless) co-efficient of Lift
p = (1/2 rho) air density
v = (mph) velocity squared
s = (sq/ft) surface area of the wing
```

[image]

Lift is interdependent to all these values - so you need to know all of them.  For any given speed, the lift will increase with denser air, larger wing area, or higher angle of attack (without stalling).

For example, a 1000lb aircraft traveling at 100mph will have more lift at a lower altitude with dense air than the same aircraft at the same speed at an altitude 5000ft higher and less dense air.

Comment: Re "... a 1000lb aircraft traveling at 100mph will have more lift...", according to your formula (and common sense!) lift does not depend on weight.  Make a duplicate of a wing out of solid lead, and it will produce exactly the same amount of lift.  The really important factors are hidden within your C "variable" (really a complicated function of shape & angle of attack),

Comment: Where did I say weight was a factor in producing lift? I was comparing all things being equal *except* air density...

Comment: In the line I quoted about the 1000 lb aircraft.  The important point here - and why the OP's question is not even wrong - is that lift is independent of weight.  A 10,000 lb aircraft with the same shape, travelling at the same speed, altitude, &c, will produce exactly the same amount of lift.  Of course the lift produced may be insufficient for flight, but that's a different issue :-)